# Increasing lockout duration on active directory

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory

Sun has a concept called Lockout Duration Multiplier; the more a user has been locked out during a certain period, the longer his lockout duration will be. This helps foil automated attempts to log in by guessing the password and dictionary attacks because of the increasing lock duration.

At the same time, it also does not annoy legitimate users as much.

A brief explanation of this can be found here:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19681-01/820-3740/adrcc/index.html

I could not find a similar concept for Active Directory and Windows management systems.  Is there a way to replicate this?

Comment: Very interesting behavior. That being said - I don't think there is a way to implement it in AD. Once a user is unlocked, the "lockout cycle" starts over as the `badPwdCount` attribute on the account is reset

Comment: Not only that but `badPwdCount` isn't replicated, meaning that if the lockout threshold is 3 bad attempts, that means I can try to login twice on DC01, twice on DC02, twice on DC03, twice on DC04, etc.

Comment: Also keep in mind the behavior that domain controllers exhibit whereby, before incrementing badPwdCount, they check the password value against the past two password history values, so badPwdCount won't be incremented if the password you entered was incorrect, but still matched one of your last two historical passwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Active Directory does not have that behavior.

Edit: Sorry.

Edit #2: A static lockout duration of, for instance, 30 minutes or an hour, is enough to make brute force attempts sufficiently useless. If Microsoft wanted to copy the "lockout duration multiplier" behavior, it wouldn't be too hard, but it would result in only a very small gain in security posture.

Comment: And possibly a very large increase in annoyance :-)